# Почему не получается манипулировать с объектом после заполнения его внутри fetch?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, async-await, fetch

У меня есть функция `getData() {...}`, внутри нее с помощью `fetch()` и `.then` заполняется объект, который объявлен в глобальной области видимости с помощью var.
После описания тела функции, я сразу же запускаю ее: `getData();` после чего вывожу заполненный внутри функции объект в консоль. Объект выводится как надо, все данные есть.
НО! как только я пытаюсь сделать какие-то манипуляции с объектом вне функции, он всегда почему-то пустой и его `length = 0`. В чем может быть проблема и как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите весь свой код текстом, пожалуйста, а не словами. В т.ч. тестовые данные объекта

Comment: @СергейМишин, 
https://jsfiddle.net/svazi89/fzcqnLhm/
Что выводит в консоль:
https://radikalno.ru/full/2020/12/20/3b3b44dc5e5959bdbfb1f70906fa22ad-full.png.html

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться, как работает ансинхронный код. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/ и https://learn.javascript.ru/async.

Comment: Кратко: 1. у вас заполнение объекта выходит позже, чем вывод в консоль и чем манипуляции с ним; 2. у объекта нет автоматического свойства `length`, в отличие от массива; 3. поскольку вывод объектов в консоль «живой», то есть отображает статус переменной тогда, когда вы пытаетесь её развернуть и посмотреть, вам может казаться, что объект заполнен  тогда же, когда вы вызывали `console.log()`, но скорее всего вы просто разворачиваете его уже после того, как асинхронный код его заполнил.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/199253)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, а не подскажете, пожалуйста, как можно код в 20 и 22 строчках переписать с помощью await? https://jsfiddle.net/svazi89/fzcqnLhm/
Сделал функцию async, с помощью await получилось вставить covidGlobalCases, а как переписать 20 и 22 строчки (теперь они 12 и 13) под await - не знаю, затрудняюсь.
https://jsfiddle.net/svazi89/fzcqnLhm/1/

Comment: Предложил один из вариантов в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант (только, кажется, вам не нужно дважды получать данные из сети по одному и тому же адресу, можно один раз):

```js
async function getData(requestOptions, countriesData) {
  //Получаем общее число случаев заражения по всей планете
  //Получаем страны и кол-во случаев заражения за весь период для каждой страны
  const res = await fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/summary', requestOptions);
  const json = await res.json();

  covidGlobalCases.innerHTML = json.Global.TotalConfirmed;

  json.Countries.forEach((country) => {
    //console.log(country.Country + ': ' + country.TotalConfirmed);
    countriesData[country.Country] = country.TotalConfirmed;
  });
}

(async function main() {
  try {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    const countriesData = {};
    await getData(requestOptions, countriesData);

    console.log(countriesData);
    console.log(Object.keys(countriesData).length);

    const sortedCountriesData = Object.keys(countriesData).sort(function(a, b) {
      return countriesData[a] - countriesData[b];
    });
    console.log(sortedCountriesData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id='covidGlobalCases'></div>
```

Comment: Я наверное не правильно объяснил, что я хочу сделать.
Внутри функции я мог производить манипуляции с данными, проблем никаких не было.
Мне нужно производить манипуляции вне функции с объектом, после того, как он будет заполнен в функции getData();
По этому у меня он и был объявлен в глобальной области видимости.
Пробовал его возвращать, ваш код в точности вставлял и делал объект глобальным, но вне функции все равно он Object.keys(countriesData).length undefined. Хотя если в своем коде я выводил просто countriesData в консоль - он заполнен. Я не понимаю этого.

Comment: Как говорят, асинхронный код заразен. Если вы хотите дождаться его работы в глобальном контексте, нужно тогда глобальный контекст обернуть в асинхронную функцию. Я исправил пример, чтобы он приблизительно делал то, что вам нужно.

Comment: А по поводу вывода в консоль я уже вам писал выше: скорее всего, вам просто кажется, что объект выводится заполненным, на самом деле он заполняется позже, а вы разворачиваете его в консоли ещё чуть позже. Там живой вывод — показывается значение на то время, когда вы по нему щелкаете, а не на то время, когда оно впервые появляется в консоли.

Comment: И я ещё раз вам советую прочитать весь раздел https://learn.javascript.ru/async , если вы ещё не читали. Это один из фундаментальных моментов для современного JS, вам нужно хорошо разобраться, прежде чем писать код для таких случаев.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я кажется понял и вроде при таком подходе все по идее должно работать.